# Multiply all number between two integer in java without using loop

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose there is a method `int Multiply(int x,int y)`. Is it possible for this method to return product of all the integers between x and y without using loop.

For example if the method is called with 3 and 5 : `Multiply(3,5)` then it should return the product : `3*4*5 = 60`.

Comment: Why no loop? Do you need to use recursion? What have you tried?

Comment: You are asking like I want to eat, But not with mouth..

Comment: try something like ``n2! / (n1-1)!`` *i.e.* for your  example **5! / 2! **

Comment: @ShreeKrishna can you use recursion? if so try the factorial approach using recursion

Comment: Its a nice question of recursion...no need to create another method for factorial, the intent of the question I feel is to use recursion and this particular method to get the product of all the numbers between x and y  [both inclusive].

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing if there is some bit-twiddling solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. Please find my attempt to solve this below, The assumption is `x is less than or equal to y`

```
public static int multiply(int x, int y){
    if(x==y){
        return x;
    }
    if(x == y-1){
        return x*y;
    }
    int product = x*y;
    product = product*multiply(x+1,y-1);
    return product;
}
```

Comment: `return x<y ? x*multiply(x+1,y) : y;`

Comment: simply wow :), though little complicated but yes it does in a single line what my code does in 7 lines...

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8's streams:

```
public static int foo (int x, int y){
  int high = x > y ? x : y;
  int low  = x > y ? y : x;
  return IntStream.rangeClosed(low, high).reduce(1, Math::multiplyExact);
}
```

Technically, there are no loops : )

Comment: i feel you need to modify your code , check for simple cases where x is not 1, like multiply(2,4) should output 2*3*4 = 24

Comment: The code definitely needs a couple of adjustments — I was kind of winging this one — but invalid stream ranges actually output an empty stream! So in combination with the fact that reduce initializes at 1: only a check for < 0s is required. Edit: adjustments made.